# Select2 is not hide when press hardware button back in Ionic 2

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, jquery-select2, ionic3

I use Ionic 2 with Select2Module ([ng2-select2 package](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2)) for autocomplete input-dropdown.

When I click on the input to display the autocomplete dropdown of select2, the keyboard appears if I want to type and expand the options.
When I click on the mobile button back, the keyboard disappears but not the dropdown. And if I press the button back again, I go back to the screen but the dropdown is still there.

Here is an example of what happens

**When I press the input for show the dropdown and display the options with the keyboard:**
[image]

**When I press the button back and the keyboard disappears but not the dropdown:**
[image]

**When I press again the button back and I return to the previous page but the dropdown is still there:**
[image]

How can I hide the dropdown when the user press the button back? What happen select2 component?

I try to solve this problem with the following code in my `app.component.ts`:

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        const overlayView = this.app._appRoot._overlayPortal._views[0];
        if( overlayView && overlayView.dismiss ){
          overlayView.dismiss();
        } else {
          this.app.goBack();
        }
      })
```

But not working. In theory with this code, the back button should hide modal popups but it does not work.

Comment: Is this `modal popup` or `page`?

Comment: @Sampath is not a `page`. But I don't know if it's a `modal popup`. I updated my question with some code.

Comment: how do you trigger openening, is it the input?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

*app.component.ts*

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
  try {
    this.viewController.dismiss()
  }
  catch(e) {
    ... no overlay component open
  }
})
```

If above won't work you can find out tons of [**solutions here**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6982).